# Apply aggregate function on subset of rows and then filter the subset based on the aggregate

Tags: mysql

I would like to first filter a table, and then calculate the average and standard deviation of certain columns of the filtered subset. After this, I would like to filter the subset further based on the average and standard deviation returned. How would I go about attempting this in one query?

This is what my table looks like

```
| id   | day                 | speed    | name |nor
 1      2017-02-03 00:00:00   -12.3      SYN    10
 2      2018-02-03 00:00:00   -6.36      SYN    13
 3      2015-02-03 00:00:00   -26.36     SYN    24
 4      2017-02-03 00:00:00   -156.36    SYN    16
 5      2017-02-03 00:00:00   -36.36     YRT    136
 6      2017-02-03 00:00:00   -16.36     SYN    13
```

After the first filter (inner query shown below), it would look like this:

```
|day                    |speed       |nor
 2017-02-03 00:00:00     12.30        10
 2018-02-03 00:00:00      6.36        13
 2017-02-03 00:00:00     16.36        24
```

Now, for this subset, I would like to find the standard deviation and average of `speed` and `nor` and filter the subset again. So for example, if the average `speed` of the 3 rows is 10 with std deviation 1, and avg `nor` is 14 with std deviation 3, when I filter values less than avg(speed) + 3 * std deviation(speed), and avg(nor) + 3 * std deviation(nor), I should get rows 1 and 2.

Here's how I tried it, but it results in `Invalid use of group function` error.

```
SELECT t1.day, t1.speed, t1.nor FROM (

SELECT report.day AS day, 
        abs(report.speed) AS speed, 
        report.nor AS nor FROM report 
WHERE 
        report.name = 'SYN' 
AND         
        report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND 
        report.speed 
BETWEEN 
        -40 AND -0.0001
) AS t1 

WHERE 
         t1.speed < AVG(t1.speed) + 3 * STD(t1.speed) 
AND 
         t1.nor < AVG(t1.speed) + 3 * STD(t1.speed)
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. You need to add an example input and the expected output for that example. If you have several example, that is also good.

Comment: You get the error because the aggregate function cannot be used in the `WHERE` part of the query. You need to use the `WHERE` part to select the rows you want to aggregate and then a `HAVING` clause to filter the aggregated result.

Comment: I tried using `HAVING` but it returns just one row which is not what I want. I will edit this and add input and expected output like you said but I'll only be able to do it later.

Comment: What is your version of Mysql?

Comment: Version is Mariadb 10.0.34

Comment: Hi @MatsKindahl I have added more details. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some things that are not entirely clear, but to give you an idea of how to approach this, I'll outline how to handle this using the data you provide.

First, I mentioned using `HAVING` in the answer, but that does not work since it is to be used with the grouped result, and here you want to filter the original table rows based on the average of a filtered table.

Second, note that the average and standard deviation of the filtered rows is not what you mention in your text, so the queries executed below will not give the result you suggest.

```
mysql> SELECT AVG(speed), STD(speed)                                                                                                                                 ->   FROM report 
    ->  WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
    ->    AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
    ->    AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001;
+---------------------+-------------------+
| AVG(speed)          | STD(speed)        |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| -11.673333644866943 | 4.106461218126736 |
+---------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, it is not 10 and 1 as you mentioned in the text above.

For your particular case, you want to use a filtered query and then execute a set of different operations on it. This is a perfect case for using *common table expressions* (CTE), which exists in MySQL 8.0. To use this, you define the `t1` table and use it multiple times in the `SELECT` body of the CTE. I only have 5.7 installed here, it would look like this if using PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH
  t1 AS (
    SELECT id, day, ABS(report.speed) AS speed, nor
      FROM report 
     WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001)
SELECT id, day, speed, nor
  FROM t1
 WHERE speed < (SELECT AVG(speed) + 3 * STDDEV_POP(speed) FROM t1)
   AND nor < (SELECT AVG(speed) + 3 * STDDEV_POP(speed) FROM t1);
```

This would result in:

```
 id |         day         | speed | nor 
----+---------------------+-------+-----
  1 | 2017-02-03 00:00:00 |  12.3 |  10
  2 | 2018-02-03 00:00:00 |  6.36 |  13
  6 | 2017-02-03 00:00:00 | 16.36 |  13
(3 rows)
```

If you are using MySQL 5.7 and it does not have CTE, you would have to take the `SELECT` body of the CTE above, and repeat the "filtered query" for each case of `t1` above, which would give you something like:

```sql
SELECT t1.day, t1.speed, t1.nor
  FROM (SELECT id, day, ABS(report.speed) AS speed, nor
          FROM report 
         WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001) AS t1
 WHERE t1.speed < (SELECT AVG(ABS(speed)) + 3 * STD(ABS(speed))
          FROM report 
     WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001)
   AND t1.nor < (SELECT AVG(ABS(speed)) + 3 * STD(ABS(speed))
          FROM report 
     WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001);
```

You might be tempted to create a derived table for the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, but that does not work because the scope containing the derived tables does not extend to the right side of the expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

**Update.** I have to partially correct myself, but here is the story about derived tables.

Attempting to create a derived table `t2` to compute the average and standard deviation and then use it in a subquery in the `WHERE`-clause will fail with the error `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.t2' doesn't exist`:

```sql
SELECT t1.day, t1.speed, t1.nor
  FROM (SELECT id, day, ABS(report.speed) AS speed, nor
          FROM report 
         WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001) AS t1,
       (SELECT AVG(ABS(speed)) AS avg, STD(ABS(speed)) AS std
          FROM report 
     WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
       AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001) AS t2
 WHERE t1.speed < (SELECT avg + 3 * std FROM t2)
   AND t1.nor < (SELECT avg + 3 * std FROM t2);
```

This is because the scope of `t2` does not extend to the *subquery* in the `WHERE`-clause. It *does* however work if you do *not* use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT t1.day, t1.speed, t1.nor
  FROM (SELECT id, day, ABS(report.speed) AS speed, nor
          FROM report 
         WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
           AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
           AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001) AS t1,
       (SELECT AVG(ABS(speed)) + 3 * STD(ABS(speed)) AS value
          FROM report 
         WHERE report.name = 'SYN' 
           AND report.day > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
           AND report.speed BETWEEN -40 AND -0.0001) AS t2
 WHERE t1.speed < t2.value
   AND t1.nor < t2.value;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you please explain the last sentence about the derived table?

Comment: @spheroid Added a more elaborate example. It was also not entirely accurate, so completed with a better example as well.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!